# Chrome extension: create tab from within an iframe in popup

Tags: iframe, google-chrome-extension, tabs, popup

In my popup page I've an iframe tag which has a button in it. When this button is clicked a function, that is included in the iframe's script, is called. This function contains a call to `chrome.tabs.create({ url: "..."});`, but I keep getting *"Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'create' of undefined".* I guess the reason is that I'm in the iframe, not in the popup page itself.

Is there a way to overcome that obscure and create a new tab from within the iframe?

**EDIT**

Here is my code.

The following is loaded into the iframe of the popup page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style/frame_style.css" media="screen" />
  <script src='jquery-1.8.3.js'></script>
  <script src='scripts/frame_functions.js'></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div>
    <button value="Click to open Google in a new tab" class='new_tab_bt'></button>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

frame_functions.js:

```
$(document).on("click", '.new_tab_bt', function(){
  openNewTab(); 
});

function openNewTab()
{
chrome.tabs.create({ url: "https://www.google.com" });
}
```

Comment: how are you adding `onclick` code to `button` in `iframe`? Can you share `iframe` and related click code?

Comment: Thanks for commenting. Added inline.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is working without any changes, I have added working code as a reference; Where is your target source html page of `iframe`, how did you reference it from browser action popup.? If this did not solve share how did you refer your `iframe` from browser action popup.

## Working Version

#### manifest.json

Simple code, registered `browser action`.

```
{
    "name": "Iframe Holder",
    "description": "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14429598/chrome-extension-create-tab-from-within-an-iframe-in-popup",
    "version": "1",
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "browser_action": {
        "default_popup": "popup.html",
        "default_title": "Iframe."
    }
}
```

#### popup.html

Included destination page in `popup` of browser action.

```
<html>

    <body>
        <iframe width="300" height="300" src="iframe.html"></iframe>
    </body>

</html>
```

#### iframe.html

Used your code and eliminated not related css files etc

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <script src='jquery.js'></script>
        <script src='iframe.js'></script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div>
            <button value="Click to open Google in a new tab" class='new_tab_bt'></button>
        </div>
    </body>

</html>
```

#### iframe.js

Used your code with no modifications

```
$(document).on("click", '.new_tab_bt', function () {
    openNewTab();
});

function openNewTab() {
    chrome.tabs.create({
        url: "https://www.google.com"
    });
}
```

Comment: Many thanks. It might be working for you because your iframe.html becomes part of the extension since it's sitting in the extension directory and included in popup.html. But I'm trying to load the iframe from a remote server along with iframe.js (I can leave iframe.js in the extension directory if this will solve the problem but I din't find a way to make it working).

Comment: @Subway: Do you see any issues in placing files in same directory?

Comment: No, it's not about the same directory. The button in the iframe is created (or not created) as per data that is placed on the remote server. You are right that I can redesign the whole system in a way that only the data will be sent from the server and the iframe will be created locally according to the data that was sent, but I'm looking for a way to leave the current design in which the iframe's content is create on the server and shown on the popup as is. Is it possible to fire a tab creation when a button included in the iframe is clicked?